# How is this application certificate valid?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I've installed an application on my macbook from line6. The certificate which signed the application has expired but is marked as a valid certificate - how is still possible? See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the signature was timestamped. In this case, signing certificate remains valid after its expiration. More details: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx (start with signature lifecycle section)

Comment: @Crypt32 could you post this as a comment so I can mark it as accepted? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several digital signature trust and lifecycle models.

If the signature is not timestamped it is invalidated along with signing certificate expiration.

When the signature is timestamped (signing time is attached to signature) it is possible to extend signature validity beyond signing (and any other related certificate, like signing and timestamping certificate chains) validity. This is because signing time is known and is set within signing certificate's validity. That is, signing certificate was fully valid and not revoked at  signing time. As the result, you can successfully validate timestamped signatures when:

- signing certificate's chain is trusted
- timestamping certificate's chain is trusted
- signed timestamp is within signing certificate's validity
- neither certificate was revoked prior to signing time (determined by revocation date in CRL and signed timestamp in signature)

More details in my blog post: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx